# I have a form with several fields and want to generate a pdf file on submit event with form fields values

Tags: c#, sitecore

I have a form with some fields like text, checkbox, dropdown and after clicking on submit button it will generate a formatted pdf file with form values. How can i generate dynamic pdf file. Please help me out.
i am currently using html form in .cshtml file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways:

1. Create a form using Acrobat and then fill form fields using iTextSharp
2. Create the doc from scratch, using PDF a library like iTextSharp (https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/)

If you have Acrobat the first mode is more simple, because you can create the document with Acrobat and then just fill form fields by code. With the second mode you have to create and format the document all by code, it is advisable only if the document is very simple.